# Python Class For loop

Tags: python, for-loop

```
class Person:
    def __ini‎t__(sel‎f, age):
        self._age = age

    @prop‎‎er‎t‎y
    def age(self):
        return self._a‎g‎e

person‎s = [Pe‎r‎son(20), Pe‎‎r‎s‎o‎n(30), Person‎(19), Pers‎on(17), Per‎son(15), Per‎‎son(25)]  

result = persons[0]

for person in persons:
    if person.age < result.age:
        result = person
```

Can someone please explain to me, what happens in this for loop? As far as I understand it checks, if the input of age is smaller than the result and if so, it "puts" it into the result variable.
The solution states 15 but how do we get there?

Comment: I don't understand what is unclear to you. The code literally says what it's doing. You have already described it correctly.

Comment: Just to say you could achieve this with `min(persons, key=attrgetter('age'))`

Comment: Did you expect a different result? Why?

Comment: `result` is just a name for an object. The name `result` is assigned to the `Person` object with the lowest `age` attribute.

Comment: I just don't know why its 15...I mean if the code iterates through persons, the first parameter already fullfills the for-loop, so why is the result not "20"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Can someone explain this code?" is not a valid question for this site.

Comment: Because once `person` is `Person(15)`, `person.age < result.age` will be true and `result` will become `Person(15)`...?

Comment: Use this site: https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Answer (score 2):

The loop cycles though the persons list and then compares their age Person.age to the Person's age in results result.age. The result at the start is set to persons[0] or Person(20), if it finds someone who is younger aka person.age < result.age the result becomes the "person". So the loop is finding the youngest person in the list.

Comment: Ahhh...thats it...I didn't follow through on the logic...sure..so it compares every array and only stores the smalles age in the variable result. Alright, got it! Thanks a lot to all of you

Comment: **list**. There is no array here, it is a **list**

Answer (score 0):

For things like this it is sometimes easier to step through the problem by writing out what is happening.

So we know we're using a list of `Person` objects, which have an assigned `age` that we can retrieve.

Starting the loop if we plug in what we have:

```py
result = persons[0] # first person in the list, Person.age = 20

for person in persons:
   if person.age < result.age:
       result = person.age
```

Iteration 1:

```py
result = 20
if 20 < 20: # this is false
    result = 20
```

Iteration 2:

```py
result = 20
if 30 < 20: # this is false
    result = 30
```

Iteration 3:

```py
result = 20
if 19 < 20: # this is true, result is reassigned
    result = 19
```

Etc. for all items in the list.

Comment: It's not quite right, I'm afraid - in the original code `result` was a Person instance, not the `Person.age` property value. OP will end up with the youngest Person.

Comment: This was meant to show the substitution of values, I agree that it is a `Person` instance that exists; however, they were expressing difficulty in following what the code was comparing which was why I rewrote it with the values instead.

Comment: Understood -- your code sample will throw an exception if anyone were to run it, which I worried has potential to cause confusion (`result` becomes an integer, so `result.age` fails on the second loop), you may just want to include a note in your answer?